# Subquery in doctrine2 notIN Function

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I'd like to select members who are not in specific service. I have 3 tables :

- `membre`
- `service`
- `membre_service` (relation between `membre` and `service`)

I'm using doctrine 2 and in SQL my query is :

```sql
SELECT m.* FROM membre m WHERE m.`id` NOT IN (
    SELECT ms.membre_id FROM membre_service ms WHERE ms.service_id != 29
)
```

In Doctrine, I do :

```php
$qb  = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb2 = $qb;
$qb2->select('m.id')
        ->from('Custom\Entity\MembreService', 'ms')
        ->leftJoin('ms.membre', 'm')
        ->where('ms.id != ?1')
        ->setParameter(1, $service);

    $qb  = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('m')
        ->from('Custom\Entity\Membre', 'm')
        ->where($qb->expr()->notIn('m.id', $qb2->getDQL())
    );
    $query  = $qb->getQuery();
    //$query->useResultCache(true, 1200, __FUNCTION__);

    return $query->getResult();
```

I got the following error :

> Semantical Error] line 0, col 123 near 'm WHERE ms.id': Error: 'm' is already defined.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The same alias cannot be defined 2 times in the same query

```
$qb  = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb2 = $qb;
$qb2->select('m.id')
    ->from('Custom\Entity\MembreService', 'ms')
    ->leftJoin('ms.membre', 'm')
    ->where('ms.id != ?1');

$qb  = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('mm')
    ->from('Custom\Entity\Membre', 'mm')
    ->where($qb->expr()->notIn('mm.id', $qb2->getDQL())
);
$qb->setParameter(1, $service);
$query  = $qb->getQuery();

return $query->getResult();
```

Ideally you should use many-to-many relation for your entity, in this case your query is going to be much simpler.

Comment: Thank for your answer! MembreService is already in many-to-many...
You really helped me out! And see my edit for the final answer.
May God Bless You...

Comment: If you are using parameters in the subquery: $qb->setParameters($qb2->getParameters()); is needed, though you might want to $qb->setParameters(array_merge($qb2->getParameters(),$qb->getParameters())) to avoid overriding parameters from the exterior query.

Comment: Hmmm... take my last comment with a grain of salt, that only appears to work in some versions of doctrine... in other versions setParameters replaces rather than adds to the parameters...

Comment: Hi, little confused as to why you instantiate `$qb` twice, once on line 1 and again on line 8? Is that necessary or just a typo?

Answer (score 16):

Actually if you are using the Symfony2 repository class you could also do the following:

```
$in = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Custom:MembreService')
    ->createQueryBuilder('ms')
    ->select('identity(ms.m)')
    ->where(ms.id != ?1);

$q = $this->createQueryBuilder('m')
    ->where($q->expr()->notIn('m.id', $in->getDQL()))
    ->setParameter(1, $service);

return $q->getQuery()->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was looking for a way to do this with different repositories, your solution did the trick.

Comment: In `$q->expr()`, what is `$q` ?

Comment: $q is an instance of QueryBuilder. The correct code would look like this:
```$q = $this->createQueryBuilder('m'); $q->where($q->expr()->notIn()....))```

Comment: You forget quotes in where clause, please add it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `(NOT) MEMBER OF`:

```
<?php
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT m.id FROM Custom\Entity\Membre WHERE :service NOT MEMBER OF m.services');
$query->setParameter('service', $service);
$ids = $query->getResult();
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples) for more examples.