# Doctrine "notIN" query builder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to builder this data query

```
select * 
from user 
where user.id not in (
    select user.id 
    from user 
    inner join repo_user 
    on user.id = repo_user.userId 
    where repo_user.repoId = $id
)
```

And I reference the answer  ['where not in' query with doctrine query builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957330/where-not-in-query-with-doctrine-query-builder)

My trying

```
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function excludeUser($id)
    {
        $q1 = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
                ->select('u.id')
                ->innerJoin('SvnAdminBundle:RepoUser', 'ru', 'WITH', "ru.userid = u.id")
                ->where("ru.repoid = $id")
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r');
        $result = $qb->where($qb->expr()->notIn('r.id', $q1))
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();

        return $result;
    }
}
```

And I get the error message

> Notice: Array to string conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give a string as second parameter of notIn, right now you are passing your result which is an array, dont fetch the result with the first query. use

```
$q1 = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
                ->select('u.id')
                ->innerJoin('SvnAdminBundle:RepoUser', 'ru', 'WITH', "ru.userid = u.id")
                ->where("ru.repoid = $id")
                ->getDQL();
```