# How to select all rows that don't have one-to-many entity with certain value using Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two entities: `Cage` and `Bird`. `Cage` has `Birds` inside so their relationship is one-to-many.

`Bird` has a field `name`. How can I select all `Cages` where there's no `Bird` with name `eagle` inside.

I was trying to do this:

```
$cages = $this->createQueryBuilder("c")
            ->leftJoin("c.birds", "b")
            ->where("b.name != :name")
            ->setParameter("name", 'eagle')
            ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

This works if there's only single `Bird` (`eagle`) in the `Cage`. Then the `Cage` is not selected which is correct behavior.

But if there are multiple `Birds` and one of them is `eagle`, the `Cage` gets selected even though the `eagle` is inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the idea, adapt table and column names as necessary:

```
SELECT * FROM cages
WHERE cage_id NOT IN
(SELECT cage_id FROM birds WHERE name='eagle');
```

So, using doctrine:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder();

$cagesWithEagles = $qb->select('b.cage_id')
    ->from('birds', 'b')
    ->where("b.name = :name")
    ->setParameter("name", 'eagle')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();

$cagesWithoutEagles = $qb->select('c.cage_id')
    ->from('cages', 'c')
    ->where($qb->expr()->notIn('c.cage_id', $cagesWithEagles))
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

(Inspired by ['where not in' query with doctrine query builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957330/where-not-in-query-with-doctrine-query-builder))

Comment: Ok, the principle is clear. I was doing this on PHP level using foreach cycles and custom arrays. This is the better way. Thank you!