# Symfony Form Query Builder

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, query-builder

I have a problem with my query builder but I do not know how to fix this error can you help me please?

So here is my problem, I want to retrieve the list of questions that are not in my questionnaire and have the same theme as my questionnaire.

Here is my code:

```
    $builder
        ->add('orderQuestion')
        ->add('idQuestion', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Question::class,
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($idTheme, $idQuestionnaire){
                $resultatQuestion = $er->createQueryBuilder('questionn')
                    ->select('questionn.id')
                    ->innerJoin('App\Entity\SurveyQuestion', 'surveyQuestion', 'WITH', 'questionn.id = surveyQuestion.idQuestion')
                    ->where('surveyQuestion.idSurvey = :idSurvey')
                ;

                $resultat = $er->createQueryBuilder('q')
                    ->leftJoin('q.surveyQuestions', 'sQ')
                    ->leftJoin('sQ.idSurvey', 's')
                    ->where('q.idTheme = :idTheme')->setParameter('idTheme', $idTheme)->setParameter(':idSurvey', $idQuestionnaire)
                    ->andWhere($er->createQueryBuilder('question')->expr()->notIn('q.id', $resultatQuestion->getDQL()))
                    ;

                return $resultat;
            },
            'choice_label' => function ($question) {
                return $question->getLabel();
            },
        ])
    ;
```

But, with this code a have this error : "Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given".

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Did you tried to remove `->getQuery()->getResult()` in the last query? You need to return a `QueryBuilder` object. Not the result of the query.

Comment: Yes i try this, but i error come because my first request return an array but i need this information for my second request

Comment: I'm talking about yours second request, not about first. The error is not about your first query, it's about value you returning. And it seems that you need to get just ids in the first query.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need

Comment: So, is this solved your problem? I have updated my answer.

Comment: No, your solution does not work

Comment: Can you show your updated code?

Comment: I put my new code

Comment: Yeap, I see. But you just need to update your question and add it there, not as an answer. So, look, also try to remove `->getResult()` from the first query, just according to [IN operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp).

Comment: I try to remove ->getResult() from my first query but I still have an error that is "Expression of type 'Doctrine\ORM\Query' not allowed in this context."

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957330) might help.

Comment: Yeap, using `$test->getDQL()` in the second query might help

Comment: I used the method of msg, it works because when I use this request on PhpMyAdmin it works but in my select it shows me the list of all my questions

Comment: I update my code and its works

Comment: It is not good that you have changed your code in the question, you could just add correct code as update in it. And it's a bit overengineering here `->andWhere($er->createQueryBuilder('question')->expr()->notIn('q.id', $resultatQuestion->getDQL()));`. It should work just with `->andWhere('q.id NOT IN ' . $resultatQuestion->getDQL())` as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

So, to be clear, as I mentioned in the comment and in the [Symfony's documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder) - `'query_builder'` can either be a `QueryBuilder` object, a callable or `null`.

This way you need to remove `->getQuery()` and `->getResult()` from your second query.

**Update**

So, thanks for the clarification from [@msg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4782169/msg) in comments. And according it, you also need to remove from the first statement `->getQuery()` and `->getResult()` too and just add there `->getDQL()`

And it should work.

Comment: Ok I delete ->getQuery()->getResult() but i have the same error

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score -1):

could you modify your code

```
$resultat = $er->createQueryBuilder('q')
                    ->leftJoin('q.surveyQuestions', 'sQ')
                    ->leftJoin('sQ.idSurvey', 's')
                    ->where('q.idTheme = :val')
                    ->andWhere('q.id NOT IN ' . $test)
                    ->setParameter('val', $idTheme)
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getResult()
                    ;
```

Comment: I'm trying this tomorrow and I'll let you know thank you in advance.

Comment: It will not solve the problem. @JohanL11 check the last comments on your answer.