# Symfony + Doctrine: How to find alle users WITHOUT a specific many-to-one value?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, one-to-many

A `Symfony` + `Doctrine` based project uses a `User` calls to manage registered users. An additional `UserMetadata` class is used to handle all kind of additional information (e.g. last login date, has visited page xy, etc.) about a user.

`UserMetadata` has a unidirectional many-to-one relationship to `User` (one user **can** have many linked metadata entries. `User` class does not know about the metadata).

```
class UserMetadata {
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */   
    protected $user;

    protected $key;
    protected $value;
```

A metadata entry is stored as key/value pair. For example, the date a user last visited a certain page is stored as `key='somePageName', value='2020-12-01'` is added. If no entry with `key='somePageName'` exists, the user has not visited this page yet.

**Goal 1:** Create a query which selects all users which have NOT visited a certain page.

Finding the users who HAVE visited a page is no problem using a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('u')
    ->from('AppBundle\Entity\User', 'u')
    ->andWhere('u.someValue = :filter1')
    ->setParameter('filer1', 'someFilterValueInUserEntity')

    ->leftJoin(UserSettingsEntry::class, 's', 'WITH', 's.user=u.id')
    ->andWhere('s.key = :key')
    ->setParameter('key', 'somePageName');
```

But how to find users WITHOUT such an entry?

**Goal 2:** Create a query which selects all users which have NOT visited a certain page, OR where the page was visited more than 6 weeks ago.

**Is this possible in the one query?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `->notIn()` method:

Get your original query results:

```
$myUsers = $qb->select('u')
    ->from('AppBundle\Entity\User', 'u')
    ->andWhere('u.someValue = :filter1')
    ->setParameter('filer1', 'someFilterValueInUserEntity')

    ->leftJoin(UserSettingsEntry::class, 's', 'WITH', 's.user=u.id')
    ->andWhere('s.key = :key')
    ->setParameter('key', 'somePageName')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Then you can use your result to filter a new query:

```
$qb->select('u')
    ->from('AppBundle\Entity\User', 'u')
    ->where($qb->expr()->notIn('u.id', $myUsers))
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13958127/4820276) and [Doctrine references](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a left join, you can simply check if the right side table entry is null, make sure to move the `s.key = :key` condition inside the join condition though.

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb
    ->select('u')
    ->from('AppBundle\Entity\User', 'u')
    ->andWhere('u.someValue = :filter1')
    ->setParameter('filer1', 'someFilterValueInUserEntity')
    ->leftJoin(UserSettingsEntry::class, 's', 'WITH', $qb->expr()->andX(
        's.user = u.id',
        's.key = :key'
    ))
    ->setParameter('key', 'allo')
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->isNull('s.id'))
;
```