# Self JOIN SQL converting to Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

This is my table:

[image]

Supposing I am passing $cameras containing cameras ids 30 and 31 my result should be 70, it is sum of 30 (for id 43, it is max Id for camera_id 31) and 40 (id 45, it is max id for camera_id 32)

I can achieve this result with this SQL statement:

```
SELECT SUM(t.number) 
FROM `count` t 
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT MAX(id) id, camera_id 
   FROM`count` 
   WHERE camera_id 
   IN $cameras 
   GROUP BY camera_id)t1 
ON t1.id = t.id
```

But I would like to convert this SQL statement to Doctrine's query. This is what I try:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder("c")
            ->select('SUM(c.number)')
            ->innerJoin(Count::class, 'c2', 'WITH' , 'c.id = c2.id')
            ->select('MAX(c2.id)')
            ->where('c2.camera IN (:value)')
            ->setParameter('value', $cameras)
            ->groupBy('c2.camera')
            ->getQuery()
```

But this query returns to me Max ids and I want to these Max ids were returned to the

> ->andWhere('SUM(c.number)')

line where they should be summed.

How can I adjust my query code?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think that happens because you have a second `select` which overrides the first one. Try removing it completely. But can you also share a sample of your db table? I don't think you actually need a self reference query to get what you need.

Comment: I added table sample. If I remove second select, I will not get max Ids.

Comment: Am I right in guessing that your end result should be `[55, 70, 94, 40]` from the rows you provided?

Comment: No, my result should be 70, it is sum of 30 (for id 43, it is max Id for camera_id 31) and 40 (id 45, it is max id for camera_id 32)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution I found is using a second builder:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
    ->select('MAX(c.id) AS max_id')
    ->where('c.camera IN (:cameras)')
    ->groupBy('c.camera');

$result = $this->createQueryBuilder('c2')
    ->select('SUM(c2.number)')
    ->where($qb->expr()->in('c2.id', $qb->getDQL()))
    ->setParameter('cameras', $cameras)
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Got the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11925750/9876136).

Comment: I get error: `Too few parameters: the query defines 1 parameters but you only bound 0`

Comment: I had to make just little modifications of your code and it works great. `$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->select('MAX(c.id) AS max_id')
            ->where('c.camera IN (:cameras)')
            ->groupBy('c.camera');
    
        $result = $this->createQueryBuilder('c2')
            ->select('SUM(c2.number)')
            ->where($qb->expr()->in('c2.id', $qb->getDQL()))
            ->setParameter('cameras', $cameras)
            ->getQuery()->getResult();` Thank You very much.